# How do I use a foreach loop to clean up this verbose patch of code?

Tags: java, android, foreach

Java/Android beginner here. I'm using a custom font in my application, and creating a `setTypeface()` statement for each piece of text is compromising my code quality.

Current code:

```
Typeface Helvetica = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Helvetica.otf");

final TextView Nike = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Nike);
final TextView Puma = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Puma);
final TextView Adidas = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Adidas);
final TextView Reebok = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Reebok);
final TextView Umbro = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Umbro);

Nike.setTypeface(Helvetica);
Puma.setTypeface(Helvetica);
Adidas.setTypeface(Helvetica);
Reebok.setTypeface(Helvetica);
Umbro.setTypeface(Helvetica);
```

How do I shorten this code? I'm thinking a foreach loop w/ an array, but I can't seem to figure it out. Would something like this be possible:

```
String[] HelveticaTextArray = {"Nike", "Puma", "Adidas", "Reebok", "Umbro"};

for ( String[] HelveticaTextArray : item ) {
    final TextView HelveticaText = (TextView).findViewById(R.id.item);
    HelveticaText.setTypeface(Helvetica);
};
```

Comment: If it is only 5 Views, it is okay,do not make things more complex.

Comment: 5 in my example and about 12-15 in my actual app. It's really quite long and ugly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store the int IDs instead of strings.

```
//String[] HelveticaTextArray = {"Nike", "Puma", "Adidas", "Reebok", "Umbro"};
int[] HelveticaTextArray = {R.id.Nike, R.id.Puma, R.id.Adidas, R.id.Reebok, R.id.Umbro}


for ( int[] HelveticaTextArray : item ) {
    final TextView HelveticaText = (TextView)findViewById(item);
    HelveticaText.setTypeface(Helvetica);
};
```

Unless you are never going to do anything with these TextViews I'd advise against doing it this way though. `findViewByID()` is a relatively expensive call, if you have a use for the TextView references later you should keep them around instead of making multiple calls to `findViewById()`

It is probably a better idea to subclass TextView with something like HelveticaTextView and set the typeface in the constructor, then use that instead of TextView and you won't have to mess with the typeface inside your Activity.

Something like this:

```
public class HelveticaTextView extends TextView{
    public HelveticaTextView(Context c){
        Typeface Helvetica = Typeface.createFromAsset(c.getAssets(), "fonts/Helvetica.otf");
        super(c);
        this.setTypeface(Helvetica);
    }
    public HelveticaTextView(Context c, AttributeSet attrs){
    Typeface Helvetica = Typeface.createFromAsset(c.getAssets(), "fonts/Helvetica.otf");
        super(c, attrs);
        this.setTypeface(Helvetica);
    }
    public HelveticaTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    Typeface Helvetica = Typeface.createFromAsset(c.getAssets(), "fonts/Helvetica.otf");
        super(c, attrs, defStyle);
        this.setTypeface(Helvetica);
    }
}
```

then in your xml layouts change

```
<TextView .../>
```

to

```
<com.your.package.name.HelveticaTextView .../>
```

Comment: Excellent reply! I agree with your advice on `findViewById` and will keep that in mind. This is my first app, so subclasses are a bit beyond my scope.

I understand the gist of it, but I can't make sense of the 3 methods in your subclass. What do they do differently to one another? And would this subclass go in it's own .java file w/ the necessary imports and such?

Comment: Yes it would go in its own .java file and yes it'll need some imports, if you are in eclipse ctrl+shift+o will fix them for you. Those are the 3 constructors that [TextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html) has. By putting the setTypeface() inside the constructor we the TextView will already have helvetica set once it is created.

Comment: Hi, I tried out your subclass but I'm getting an error. Can you help me? Had to change a couple of things because of errors. I placed `super(c, ..)` line above `Typeface Helvetica ...`. In the last constructor, I changed `Context context` to `Context c`. Then used my `<com.my.package.HelveticaTextView />` and it says the class couldn't be instantiated. It claimed that `Typeface.createfromasset() is not supported`. It's a shame because I really like this subclass idea.

Comment: It's strange - despite these errors I'm getting, it did actually work. I tested it in the emulator and the font is Helvetica. But these errors worry me and also render the graphical layout of the XML kind of useless.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are doing the same thing for each `TextView` I would be inclined to create a convenience method that does what you need, passing in the `R.id.xxx` and font.  E.g.,

```
private void initializeViews() {
    Typeface Helvetica = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Helvetica.otf");

    final TextView Nike = initializeTextView(R.id.Nike, Helvetica);
    final TextView Puma = initializeTextView(R.id.Puma, Helvetica);
    final TextView Adidas = initializeTextView(R.id.Adidas, Helvetica);
    final TextView Reebok = initializeTextView(R.id.Reebok, Helvetica);
    final TextView Umbro = initializeTextView(R.id.Umbro, Helvetica);

}

private TextView initializeTextView(int textViewId, Typeface typeface) {
    TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(textViewId);
    if (textView != null)
        textView.setTypeface(typeface);
    else
        Log.e(TAG, "some error message");
    return textView;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int[] HelveticaArray = {R.id.Nike, R.id.Puma, R.id.Reebok, R.id.Umbro};

for (int item : HelveticaArray) {
    ((TextView).findViewById(item)).setTypeFace(Helvetica);
}
```

Comment: Nice, simple and clean. Thanks. Could you explain why your `for` statement reads `(int item : HelveticaArray)` instead of `(int[] HelveticaArray : item)`? Are they equivalent?

Comment: I have only seen it done the way I have done it. Even the Java tutorials use my approach in examples.

Answer (score 1):

Probably like this:

```
TextView[] textViews = { (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Nike), (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Puma) };

for (TextView view : textViews) {
   view.setTypeface(Helvetica);
}
```